# how to do facebook login permission ReactJS

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, reactjs, ecmascript-6

How can I write Facebook login permission in ReactJS way?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Grid } from 'semantic-ui-react';

import './SignUp.css';


class SignUp extends Component{

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.login =this.login.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
  FB.init({
    appId: 'xxxxxx',
    status: true,
    cookie: true,
    xfbml: true
  });
};

(function (doc) {
  var js;
  var id = 'facebook-jssdk';
  var ref = doc.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  if (doc.getElementById(id)) {
    return;
  }
  js = doc.createElement('script');
  js.id = id;
  js.async = true;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
  ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
}(document));
    }


    login(){
        FB.login(function(response){
            if(response.status==="connected"){
                console.log('jdjsd');
            } else if(response.status==="not_authorized"){
                console.log('dkndsjn');
            } else{
                console.log('dhbdsbdss  ');
            }
        });
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div className="message">
            <Grid divided="vertically" columns="equal">


            <Grid.Row>
            <Grid.Column>
            <div className="UserDetails">

            </div>

            <div id='social-login-button-facebook'>

                <button onClick={this.login}>Login</button>
                <div className="fb-login-button" data-max-rows="1" data-size="medium" data-button-type="login_with" data-show-faces="false" data-auto-logout-link="true" data-use-continue-as="false"></div>
            </div>
            </Grid.Column>
            </Grid.Row>


            </Grid>
            </div>

            );
    }
}

export default SignUp;
```

'FB' is not defined un-def message is shown in console
How can I solve it?
I have also tried using js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"; but it didn't work as well?

Comment: more info please. does the js sdk get loaded? check out the network tab.

Comment: Yes I have included that in index.html file. Should I use npm module like facebook-node-sdk or not?

Comment: Yes facebook sdk is been loaded ,I have checked the network tab .Should I use npm Fb sdk?

Comment: ok, it should actually work like that, does the fbAsyncInit function get called?